# matching variables across two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

reasonably new to php here,

I am trying to create a matching query using a php statement. The query is spread across two tables in the same database.

```
  $check_availability =  "select * 
                    from tutors, students 
                    where tutor_availability=student_availability";


$run_1 = mysql_query($check_availability);


      if(mysql_num_rows($run_1)>0){

     echo  'match found';

     }else{

      echo  'no match'</script>";


  }
```

At the moment the true part of the "if" statement works but the "false" part does not seem to be working. I need to make sure the "availability" of both the "student" and "tutor" are the same or different

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: While formatting your code, I came across two syntax errors: line 6 (now, after my edit) has one additional `"` in front, and there is a unmatched `}`at the end. I left those, as they may have been in the original file, too.

Comment: What's the deal with those `//javascript`comments BTW?

Comment: I basically had javascript alerts where I have "//javascript" they just weren't really relevant. Probably should have explained that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$check_availability= "select * 
                     from tutors  
                     INNER JOIN
                               students 
                      ON '$tutor_availability'='$student_availability'";
  $run_1 = mysql_query($check_availability);

if(mysql_num_rows($run_1)>0){
     echo  'we have a match'; //javascript
 } else{
     echo  'no match found'; //javascript
 }
```

Comment: I thought the INNER JOIN would work but it seems to be returning the same result

Comment: Is there any error you getting while running the code?

Comment: no it just doesn't return the desired result. I actually get the same result as before; the "true" statement works but the "false" one doesn't

Comment: I think you must have to add one more condition there, either for the student or tutor. As if you want to check it with the student then "WHERE students.id = $student_id" or "WHERE tutors.id = $tutor_id". This query is finding the match in whole table and I think there must be one match for tutor and student availability. Hence always the "if" true found.

Comment: `tutor_availability` and `student_availability` are database columns, not php variables

Answer (score 0):

try using join and the status column in your table (if any)

```
// my old query
//$check_availability = "select * from tutors
//join students on students.students_id = tutors.student_id
//where students.status= 'available'
//and tutors.status= 'available'"

// your original query
 $check_availability =  "select * 
                    from tutors, students 
                    where tutor_availability=student_availability";

$run_1 = mysql_query($check_availability);
if(mysql_num_rows($run_1)>0){
   echo  'no match found'; //javascript
    }else{
   echo  'we have a match'; //javascript            
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have that status set as "avaialble" rather it is set as an option (i.e. students and tutors pick an "option" of what time suits them best).  I want them both to have to same "option" selection. Can this piece of code be updated to take that into account?

Comment: See my updated answer. I take it both table has a column with the same values, right? If yes, then ignore my old query. It's has the same effect as your query. So the problem must be somewhere with your if - else values. You've got the message order wrong. This line `if(mysql_num_rows($run_1)>0)` means if the query **had** a result, then do something. Else do another function. Hope it helps.